# How is this kind of structure made?

Tags: building, design

Recently I found a MOC made by Headzsets from Instagram, in particular this interesting structure from his EVA work. Here is a picture of his structure:

[image]
(https://www.instagram.com/p/BtCymDRHJx6/)

How does he have two 1 x 1 x 2/3 slopes like this? Are there any sets with this kind of structure that I can buy on the market so I can learn this building technique?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to add a little to the answer by TheBrickBlogger, the blue piece holding the purple 1x1 slope is likely this one:

[image]

Here is a really simple example of one of the many ways this can be accomplished:

[image]

The hollow stud allows positioning to be "jumped". Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Thanks JohnnyB.

Comment: How can I add two answer as “answer”? Yours and brickblogger’s answers are both very helpful

Comment: @Tasca Qiu - You can't choose more than one.  Normally it would just come down to whichever answer you feel helped you the most.  If you feel more than one answer is eligible for "correct", then choosing the answer posted first would be more ethical in my opinion.

Answer (score 10):

The black cheese-slope is attached to the stud below, and the purple cheese-slope is attached to the upside-down stud above it. The two cheese slopes are not attached to each other, but are held in place by the studs and the other pieces around them.

Cheese-slope techniques have been extensively researched by LEGO fan Katie Walker, who is well known for her cheese-slope mosaics. Her research into the techniques has been used by many other LEGO fans and also published in books.

If you would like to understand the techniques better, I highly recommend the following article by Katie: [Cheese-Slope Mosaics: A Tutorial](http://mosaicbricks.blogspot.com/2012/06/cheese-slope-mosaics-tutorial.html) It includes extensive explanation of the techniques as well as pictures with demonstrations.

Comment: Thanks! That’s exactly what I need!